# Is it possible to find out when a user changed their password?

Tags: security, openbsd

Or to see **which** user caused the security notice that `/etc/spwd.db` was changed?

Comment: The `passwd` struct defined in `pwd.h` has a `time_t pw_change` field. However, writing a naive C program to read the password database using `getpwent(3)` only returns zeros...  I wonder if there was a decision taken at some point to not use that field?

Comment: Thanks for checking that @Kusalananda ... I'd wonder the same thing. While I appreciate that privacy is an important part of security I find the lack of auditability here inappropriate.

Comment: Well, it's simple to set up process accounting (see `/etc/rc.conf`) and then use `lastcomm` to figure out exactly who used `passwd` and when (as long as they do it while process accounting is activated).  The fact that you have not enabled process accounting is no fault of the OpenBSD devs.  My initial comment was only referring to trying to use the actual password database itself to get at the info.

Comment: @Kusalananda I do believe that process accounting will only store the euid, and that `passwd` runs with with root setuid. It's still possible to trace it to the parents using acct-dump, but it's pretty cumbersome. I actually wrote a tool at work that reads `pacct`, filter it according to every possible attribute and even shows `pstree`-like output, but I've never had the time to release it to the open source community (a thing that I've never done).

Comment: You will get two lines of output from `lastcomm` if a user changes their password: One for running the `passwd` utility and one (from root) running `pwd_mkdb` (on the same TTY). All commands are accounted.

Comment: Thanks again, I was unaware of that option (I come from the linux neck of the woods and have kind of inherited two OpenBSD machines, lone islands in a sea of 200+ linux machines) and was surprised that I can't find a trace of that change in any of the logs.

Comment: I'll let this simmer for now to see whether somebody picks it up and writes a proper answer. If nobody does, I might come back to it later. I'm not the expert, and I'd rather that e.g. @aviro wrote something (they have obviously worked with OpenBSD accounting before) than me, who would need to do a lot of testing to get things right.

Comment: @tink FYI, process accounting, though originated from BSD, exists in Linux for a very long time and is even more advanced, since it keeps additional details of each process such as the exit code and the ppid. Unfortunately the tools that display it (`lastcomm` and on the GNU implementation also `dump-acct`) are difficult to parse and to understand, so it's a pretty obscure and underutilized feature. One day I'll release my tool that analyzes the `pacct` file and change the world. ;)

Comment: @aviro =} Can't wait! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OpenBSD, you need to start process accounting wuth the [`accton`](https://man.openbsd.org/accton.8) command:

```
touch /var/account/acct   # The file has to exist before accton
accton /var/account/acct
```

To have accton enabled at boot time, use:

```
rcctl enable accounting
```

which sets `accounting=YES` in `/etc/rc.conf.local`.

Anyway, now that you have process accounting enabled, you can use [`lastcomm`](https://man.openbsd.org/lastcomm.1) to view the list of executed commands, and search for processes named `passwd` and `pwd_mkdb`. The output will be shown in reverse, where latest processes are displayed first (according to their termination time, not the time they started):

```
$ lastcomm passwd pwd_mkdb
passwd[18349]                         -       root                             ttyC1      0.28 secs Thu Mar 28 11:02 (0:00:17.39)
pwd_mkdb[27720]                       -       root                             ttyC1      0.00 secs Thu Mar 28 11:02 (0:00:00.00)
passwd[58119]                         -F      aviro                            ttyC1      0.00 secs Thu Mar 28 11:02 (0:00:00.00)
passwd[1586]                          -       root                             ttyC0      0.22 secs Thu Mar 28 10:11 (0:00:10.02)
pwd_mkdb[27986]                       -       root                             ttyC0      0.00 secs Thu Mar 28 10:11 (0:00:00.00)
passwd[64663]                         -F      aviro                            ttyC0      0.00 secs Thu Mar 28 10:11 (0:00:00.00)
```

Every successful password change will show in the history at least three processes (more or less at the same time, and also at the same tty:

1. `passwd` process owned by root. This command has to be run with elevated privileges, so the exexutable file has the setuid bit set, thus it has root's effective uid.
2. `pwd_mkdb` command also owned by root. It's self explanatory.
3. And another `passwd`, this time under user that changed the password as the owner. This is a process that's forked from the original `passwd` command to check if the password is strong enough, and [drops privileges](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/ad9f77901f0c69b84bd14308e9b461bb22fd4236/usr.bin/passwd/pwd_check.c#L113) back to the real uid. This is fortunate, because if it weren't for this low privileged child with under the original uid, you had no way to know who ran the command. This process might appear more than one time, if the user provided a password that didn't adhere to the requirements and had to provide a different password.

Comment: Just to say that I believe the two first commands are automatically executed by the system's `rc` scripts if the system is booted with `accounting=YES` in `/etc/rc.conf.local`.

Comment: @Kusalananda right, and I mentioned it also in my answer. But if you want to start accounting without rebooting the system, you'll have to run them manually.

Comment: Thank you @aviro - the output is a bit more garrulous and uglier than I hoped for, but it will have to do :) ... I'll ask my colleagues what they think about making `accounting` happen in our environment. Do you have an estimate regarding the growth rate of accounting data on a system that doesn't see too many interactive logins? The machines in question only serve as vpn servers and receive some love when they let us know that `syspatch`es are available.

Comment: @aviro Sorry, I misread that part. I read it as if you said setting `accounting=YES` was optional, which it wouldn't be unless you only wanted to turn it on _manually_ and temporarily.

Comment: @tink On my personal system, it's a matter of about 500 KB of data per day, which is rotated on a daily basis and kept for four days.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda